problem in sending json data to x-ui api for updating inbound data
I use this code to update x-ui inbounds by their id's.
The value of $user_inb_remark is inb-547724, as string.
The value of $inbound_port is 1026, as integer.
The value of $inbound_address is 161.35.168.***, as string.
The response code is success and inbound successfully update. But xray status change to Error, I see xray log.
This is error line of log file:

2024/04/12 18:12:48 ERROR - X-UI: Failure in running xray-core: exit status 23 2024/04/12 18:12:48 INFO - XRAY: infra/conf/serial: Reading config: bin/config.json.`


Failed to start: main: failed to load config files: [bin/config.json] > infra/conf: failed to load inbound detour config. > json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field DokodemoConfig.followRedirect of type bool`

Please help me if you know. Thanks.
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://'.$servers[$x].':27017/panel/api/inbounds/update/' . $inbound_id,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => '{
        "enable": true,
        "remark": "'.$user_inb_remark_server.'",
        "listen": "",
        "port": '.$inbound_port.',
        "protocol": "dokodemo-door",
        "expiryTime": 0,
        "settings": "{\\"address\\":\\"'.$inbound_address.'\\",\\"port\\":\\'.$inbound_port.'\\,\\"network\\":\\"tcp,udp\\",\\"followRedirect\\":\\"true\\"}",
        "sniffing": "{\\"enabled\\":false,\\"destOverride\\":[\\"http\\",\\"tls\\",\\"quic\\",\\"fakedns\\"]}"
    }',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Accept: application/json',
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Cookie: session=MTcxMjAxNDg1NXxEWDhFQVFMX2dBQUJFQUVRQUFCMV80QUFBUVp6ZEhKcGJtY01EQUFLVEU5SFNVNWZWVk5GVWhoNExYVnBMMlJoZEdGaVlYTmxMMjF2WkdWc0xsVnpaWExfZ1FNQkFRUlZjMlZ5QWYtQ0FBRUVBUUpKWkFFRUFBRUlWWE5sY201aGJXVUJEQUFCQ0ZCaGMzTjNiM0prQVF3QUFRdE1iMmRwYmxObFkzSmxkQUVNQUFBQUhfLUNIQUVDQVF0dFlYTjBaWEprYVhOamJ3RUtTRzlxYWtCMGNHMDNPQUE9fHcImxR8F1Brep_X3qMP1zUbqpcUc-XqKboczFcDIpJk'
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;


sorry my bad english and sorry for any mistakes in adding code blocks to code.

If you're getting a success response, your problem is most likely on the other (receiving) end. As a sidenote - don't create a JSON like string. Create an array first, and then encode it to a JSON.

If you're unsure how to create a JSON from an array, take a look here.
